# OPC UA Server access - BadRequestTimeout

Tags: opc

During our development I've been running a V5.19 Kepware Server with UA access. This has been working fine until our Server machine (Windows 7) suddenly restarted. Now none of our applications can connect via UA - BadRequestTimeout error is returned. DA access is OK, it's just the UA clients that cannot connect.

I've done the usual Google and no useful information is returned other than telling me what the numerical value of the error code is, which I already knew.

The UA configuration of the server looks fine - i.e. it hasn't changed. None of the clients have changed.

Can someone please shed some light on this?

Thanks

Steve

Comment: Have you re-initialized Kepware yet? Tried looking at Wireshark to verify that your client requests are being sent to the server and actually being ignored?

Comment: Yes, Kepware's runtime has been reinitialised.

Answer (score 0):

The Server's UA Configuration had Trusted Server and Trusted Client entries (both of which were unnecessary).

I removed both of these and suddenly UA connections were allowed.

Not sure why removing these made any difference - these had been in place for a long time, when the server was initially installed.

Comment: Heh, and now I'm receiving "Certificate is not trusted." :)